# How to fill a lookup field via C# Plugin in Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

there is a contact entity; within it a City lookup field,
creating a new contact (given details firstname, lastname, city) Via console App.
i cant seem to understand how to fill the lookup field...?
heres my code:

```
// here supposed to pass in addition to lastname, A lookup parameter to fill after finding the contact
static void FillContactLookupByLastname(string lastname /*, Lookup City*/) 
        {
            ConditionExpression condition1 = new ConditionExpression();
            condition1.AttributeName = "lastname";
            condition1.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
            condition1.Values.Add(lastname);

            FilterExpression filter1 = new FilterExpression();
            filter1.Conditions.Add(condition1);

            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("contact");
            query.ColumnSet.AddColumns("firstname", "lastname");
            query.Criteria.AddFilter(filter1);

            EntityCollection result1 = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
            Console.WriteLine(); Console.WriteLine("Query using Query Expression with ConditionExpression and FilterExpression");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
            foreach (var a in result1.Entities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + a.Attributes["firstname"] + " " + a.Attributes["lastname"]);
//here after finding the contact with the lastname, it has a lookup field that i need to fill but i dont know how
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with lookup fields using [EntityReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) class.
Pass the `EntityReference` parameter this way

```
static void FillContactLookupByLastname(string lastname, EntityReference city)
```

then fill the value

```
a["city"] = city;
```

also don't forget to call `Update` method for the entity

```
crmService.Update(a);
```